# Spacing of enumerate or itemize inside \vtop

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, line-spacing

Please look at the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

123\vtop{\hsize2cm\linewidth\hsize
     \begin{enumerate}[nosep]%
     \item My baseline is wrong!
     \item 123
     \end{enumerate}}

\end{document}
```

Sorry for using TeX primitives in LaTeX but MWEs in LaTeX can be written faster. I usually use Plain TeX and there is the same problem with selfmade enumerates and itemizes (that behave similar to the ones
from the `enumitem` package with the `[nosep]` option).

How can I get the right baseline inside `\vtop`? Where does the misalignment come from? Can you tell me the reason? I would like to learn mor about TeX.

[image]

Comment: The baseline is correct if I use `\begin{minipage}[t]{2cm}...\end{minipage}`.

Comment: Yes, but is there a solution for Plain TeX?

Comment: I'm not clairvoyant, sorry. Without knowing how *you* define lists, can you think anybody can help?

Comment: I took the lists from LaTeX 2.09 and adapted them to Plain TeX. I set the verical skips to 0 to make them compact.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple workaround:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{enumitem}

    \begin{document}

    123\vtop{\hsize2cm\linewidth\hsize\vspace*{\dimexpr1pt-\topsep\relax}
         \begin{enumerate}[nosep]%
         \item My baseline is wrong!
         \item 123
         \end{enumerate}}

    \end{document}
```

[image]